# Jquery Object and Array implementation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an Object

```
let data =  {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: {
            abc: "ak",
            bcd: "gh",
            cfv: "ht"
        }
    }
```

then I have variables which I need to show with these object value

```
   let abc = "first 1", bcd="sec2", cfv="third3" , def="fourth 4", tdf = "fifth 5";
```

Now the Object will come in API call it can be any of these variable.

How can I match the variable name with the object data.c.(object key) and concatinate their value.

for example the output should be
As we have (abc, bcd, cfv) as our object key then the output would be

```
first 1ak ==> that is the value of (abc + data.c["abc"])
sec2gh    ==> that is the value of (bcd + data.c["bcd"])
third3ht  ==> that is the value of (cfv + data.c["cfv"])
```

I tried using Object.keys() method so from this method we will get the object keys in array then how can I match with the variable name -
Object.keys(data.c);
==> ["abc", "bcd", "cfv"]    (After this how can I proceed to match the variable and show their values?)

Shall I loop throught the object that (data.c)?

Please help me giving some ideas to achieve this implementation.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible for you to amend the format of your `abc`, `bcd` etc. variables to be the properties in an object, then this problem becomes trivial. You can use `flatMap()` to create a new array of the output values by linking the properties of the two target objects, like this:

```js
let values = {
  abc: "first 1",
  bcd: "sec2",
  cfv: "third3",
  def: "fourth 4",
  tdf: "fifth 5"
}

let data = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: {
    abc: "ak",
    bcd: "gh",
    cfv: "ht"
  }
}

let output = Object.keys(values).flatMap(k => data.c.hasOwnProperty(k) ? values[k] + data.c[k] : []);
console.log(output);
```